# How to post a multi line json string as body in curl inside bash script

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

body=$(cat  << EOF
{
    "CreatedBy":  "$(hostname -f)",
    "Id":  "$(uuidgen)",
    "Type":  "TestAlertType",
    "AlertCategory":  "NonUrgent"
    }
EOF
)


curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d $body https://dev.cloudapp.net/v1/
```

But I get invalid json error on post. What am i missing?

Comment: You need to quote your expansion: `"$body"`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This worked

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "$body" https://dev.cloudapp.net/v1/
```

Comment: If the content of `$body` has/needs new lines / carriage returns (e.g. `\n`), then you need to add `IFS=$"\n"` before creating `$body` with `cat` and `EOF` otherwise when using `$body` later on the new lines disappear, no matter if you use double quotes like `"$body"`.